# Telerik exception: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Type'

Tags: telerik

"Cannot create an object of type 'System.Type' from its string representation 'System.Int32' for the 'DataType' property" Received when publishing to server.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/input/295172.aspx#1144202

Issue was with different versions on the server between my Telerik.Web.Design.dll and Telerik.Web.UI.dll.